# Scraping a section of webpage based on text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape ids in a certain section of this page https://www.flashscore.com/football/chile/primera-division/
Code:

```
table = soup.find('div', id='live-table')
__ = table.find_all('div', title='Click for match detail!')
for _ in __:
    id_ = _.get('id')
    print(id_)

OUTPUT

g_1_MuYy33R0
g_1_rkZX3qCf
g_1_44Nt2Nt7
g_1_SIC2l4C7
g_1_Ee6nhnDr
g_1_f5EfjQse
g_1_dKeii6Sl
g_1_rRfkC74E
g_1_xlfgBRJK
g_1_lSDbkpc1
g_1_G0zIx7De
g_1_zkJKwmbk
g_1_rDFGc8kL
g_1_4MGCblzF
g_1_8fN30A52
g_1_zPZT4Pdl
...
```

I want to get only those in Today's Matches
[image]

Expected Output

```
g_1_MuYy33R0
g_1_rkZX3qCf
g_1_44Nt2Nt7
```

Comment: If you only want the first 3 items, then you could use list slicing `__ = table.find_all('div', title='Click for match detail!')[0:3]` the `[0:3]` will shrink the list to only contain the first 3 items `g_1_MuYy33R0, g_1_rkZX3qCf, g_1_44Nt2Nt7`.

Comment: In this case are 3 sometimes could be more or less, so I have to select that part of the page

Comment: what, sorry don't understand

Comment: all of them are in first `section` in `id="live-table` so you can use `find("section")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want values in first section so use `find('section')` to get first section.

```
section = soup.find('div', id='live-table').find('section')

for item in section.find_all('div', title='Click for match detail!'):
    print(item.get('id'))
```

Only this section has also class `event--live` which you can use

```
section = soup.find('section', class_='event--live')

for item in section.find_all('div', title='Click for match detail!'):
    print(item.get('id'))
```

---

**EDIT:**

Minimal working code

```
import selenium.webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import time

url = 'https://www.flashscore.com/football/chile/primera-division/'

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(5)

soup = BS(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

print('--- version 1 ---')

section = soup.find('div', id='live-table').find('section')

for item in section.find_all('div', title='Click for match detail!'):
    print(item.get('id'))

print('--- version 2 ---')

section = soup.find('section', class_='event--live')

for item in section.find_all('div', title='Click for match detail!'):
    print(item.get('id'))
```